# Angular - Overlay

Tags: html, angular, typescript, overlay

I created an overlay in a project based on the example :
https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/

In my component Html :

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-8">
     Some Infos here
     <button type="button" (click)="isOpen = !isOpen" cdkOverlayOrigin #originOverlay="cdkOverlayOrigin" class="btn btn-success"><fa-icon icon="check"></fa-icon><span>Buy</span></button>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template cdkConnectedOverlay [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="originOverlay" [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isOpen">
  <div>This is my tooltip</div>
</ng-template>
```

Then i added the line `isOpen = false;` in my component.ts and the import in my global app.module : `OverlayModule`

On the button code line, I have this error showing up :
`No directive found with exportAs 'cdkOverlayOrigin'`

Answer (score 1):

I have replicated your same code in stackblitz and it seems to work fine for me. You must have forgotten one of the packages. @angular/material also needs @angular/cdk for this to work.

You can check that the code is working here.

[Link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nthzd8?file=src/app/app.module.ts)